# Resursive string replacement with escaping in Python

Tags: python, string, recursion, escaping, formatter

I made a simple script in Python to do some project generation based on sources directory structure. In it I used `Formatter` as it proved quite handy with the ability to use a dictionary (also nested!) for replacement strings.

Yet now, while extending the script, I need a more sophisticated replacement. Firstly I would like to have the replacement be recursive. A string substituted for a field might need formatting on its own (using same arguments). And secondly I need to be able to escape final string according to provided function (the only use case so far is `re.escape` to escape for regular expressions).

I looked for something build-in in Python but didn’t found anything useful. `Formatter` (as provided) obviously doesn’t meet those criteria.

---

My first try was to use a simple function like:

```
def expand_vars(string, vars):
    while True:
        expanded = string.format(**vars)
        if expanded == string:
            break
        string = expanded
    return string
```

It simply keeps calling `format` until nothing more changes in the string (which means all fields were substituted).

Yet it is not easy to embed here escaping. I need to escape only substituted values (not entire `string`) and only the final value (escaping on each call would result in multi-escaping some parts of the string).

Also another issue of this function is that it could unintentionally create fields that are not fields. When one of the fields ends as a string `{a` while another one ends as `b}` in next iteration we have unexpected field `{ab}`. (Well, it could be considered a feature but I did not perceive it that way in my case.)

---

Another approach was to subclass `Formatter`. I ended up with something like that:

```
class RecursiveEscapingFormatter(Formatter):
    def __init__(self, escape=None):
        Formatter.__init__(self)
        self.escape = escape

    def get_field(self, field_name, args, kwargs):
        obj, arg_used = super(RecursiveEscapingFormatter, self).get_field(field_name, args, kwargs)
        if self.escape is None:
            nonEscapingFormatter = self
        else:
            nonEscapingFormatter = copy.copy(self);
            nonEscapingFormatter.escape = None
        obj = nonEscapingFormatter.vformat(obj, args, kwargs)
        return obj, arg_used

    def convert_field(self, value, conversion):
        result = super(RecursiveEscapingFormatter, self).convert_field(value, conversion)
        if self.escape is not None:
            result = self.escape(result)
        return result
```

Now the issue is that I cannot assure proper call to `check_unused_args`. I don’t see way to reasonably (=not requiring entire class overwrite) keep track of arguments used by the recursive call in `get_field`. I don’t need that myself but making a proper class (a one that could be later on inherited from…) requires proper handling of `check_unused_args`. How to do that?

---

Or maybe is there a better approach to the issue (of recursive replacement with escaping)?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and here's how i've solved it.

```
from string import Formatter

class RecursivelySubstitutedDictionary:
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self.formatter = Formatter()
        self.dictionary = dictionary
        self.substituting = set([])

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if(key in self.substituting):
            raise ValueError("Cyclic reference. Key: %s." % key)
        self.substituting.add(key)
        unsubstitutedval = self.dictionary[key]
        substitutedval = self.formatter.vformat(unsubstitutedval,[],self)
        self.substituting.remove(key)
        return substitutedval
```

Example usage

```
regulardict = {
    'hi': 'hello {arg}',
    'arg': '{arg_1}{arg_2}',
    'arg_1': 'wo',
    'arg_2': 'rld',
}

print RecursivelySubstitutedDictionary(regulardict)['hi']
# prints hello world



cyclicdict = {
    'hi': 'hello {arg}',
    'arg': '{hi}',
}

print RecursivelySubstitutedDictionary(cyclicdict)['hi']
# raises ValueError: Cyclic reference. Key: hi.
```

You may also consider caching substituted vals and clearing the cache if `__setitem__` is called. At least that's what i'm doing in my original code.

Comment: But that is not a `Formatter`. Also it requires passing keys alone rather than full strings with embedded keys. And finally there is no escaping.

Comment: It is an interesting approach! But that which does your `RecursivelySubstitutedDictionary` the `Formatter` from my question does already (even more if you include escaping).